# How to modify a function in a page using Bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, function, bookmarklet

Lets say I have an HTML page which has its own function `myFunction()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("stack overflow");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to change the `myFunction()`definition like this

```
function myFunction() {
    //alert("stack overflow");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

using bookmarklet.So is there any way to change the def temporarily ?
I tried using the Chrome Console to change its def and also remain successful,but I want to change it using bookmarklets.So please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a global, you can do this in your bookmarklet:

```
var oldFunction = myFunction;
myFunction = function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
};
```

Or if you enclose your bookmarklet in a scping function (usually a good idea), probably store the old value on a `window` property instead of a local var (so you can access it from another bookmarklet to restore it later):

```
window.oldFunction = myFunction;
myFunction = function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
};
```

Another bookmarklet could set it back again:

```
myFunction = window.oldFunction; // or just = oldFunction if using a local var
```

Live Example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("Original function");
}
document.getElementById("btn-override").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.oldFunction = myFunction;
  myFunction = function() {
    alert("New function");
  };
}, false);
document.getElementById("btn-restore").addEventListener("click", function() {
  myFunction = window.oldFunction;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn-call" value="Click to call myFunction" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="button" id="btn-override" value="Click to override it">
<input type="button" id="btn-restore" value="Click to restore it">
```

Comment: Hi Crowder thanks for your suggestion .but if the function contains jQuery inside it and I want to replace it then could it be possible using bookmarklet to change the function def?

Comment: @user3722346: It doesn't matter what the function has inside it at all.

Comment: Thank you a lot.It worked. I want to be connected with you  .If you have any mail Id ,Can you please send a blank mail to my mail helptosatya@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    javascript: myFunction = function(){console.log('c')}
```